# I'm not Jack. But who am I?

Tags: riddle

What or who am I?

> My name is not Jack, to many this is my name
>
> A mighty empire brought me to fame
>
> Though now it is gone, I am still around
>
> And sometimes I even make people feel proud
>
> Together I brought millions of people
>
> Beneath me has died patriotic people
>
> A mish-mash of cultures, that's who I am
>
> Although the dragons do think, that I ignore them

Comment: "bought me to fame" ? Is that correct?

Comment: @ErikE edited, "brought" would be more correct (I think)... I never know which to use.

Comment: I could see "bought me fame", but with the preposition it would have to be "brought me to fame".

Comment: Got me - I don't know Jack.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Answer:

> [image: flag]

Explanation:

*My name is not Jack, to many this is my name*

> Many people call the UK flag the Union Jack, though that's not its official name.

*A mighty empire bought me to fame*

> The [British Empire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Empire).

*Though now it is gone, I am still around*

> The British Empire collapsed in the early-to-mid 20th century, but the flag is still used.

*And sometimes I even make people feel proud*

> Nationalism and patriotic feeling.

*Together I brought millions of people*

> There are more than 60 million people in Britain.

*Beneath me has died patriotic people*

> Many soldiers have died in war beneath this flag.

*A mish-mash of cultures, that's who I am*

> Britain is indeed a mish-mash of cultures: English, Scottish, Irish, Welsh, with history and customs taken from the Normans, the Saxons, the Norse, various Germanic tribes, ...

*Although the dragons do think, that I ignore them*

> The flag contains elements of the English, Scottish, and Irish flags, but not the Welsh flag with its dragon.

Answer (score 13):

You are:

> Union Jack (the British flag, dragon part being related to St. George's cross).

Comment: Correct (sorta, the name's Union Flag), however, you should put your reasoning (as every line does give a hint)

Answer (score 1):

It might also be a

> headphone jack

Explanation:

*My name is not Jack, to many this is my name*

> It is not officially called jack, but it is often referred to as a headphone jack.

*A mighty empire bought me to fame*

> It became very popular after it came out in Walkman, mighty empire being Sony.

*Though now it is gone, I am still around*

> As we all know it iPhone 7 doesn't have a headphone jack anymore, but it is still widely used in basically every other phone and a bunch of other machines.

*And sometimes I even make people feel proud*

> Some people might be proud of having it in their phone and mock those with iPhone 7.

*Together I brought millions of people*

> People can connect with each other by speaking through headphones that connect to a headphone jack

*Beneath me has died patriotic people*

> Was Steve Jobs patriotic?

*A mish-mash of cultures, that's who I am*

> Regardless of culture, everyone uses a headphone jack.

*Although the dragons do think, that I ignore them*

> Although dragons might think, headphone jack don't want none of that so he just ignores those dragons!

I know a few of the answers are quite far-fetched, but that's the only Jack I could think of while reading this riddle.